# Match Text in two tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to match two tables as below.

**Table 1:**

| Article Title | ID Number |
| --- | --- |
| University B: Genetic Mutations in Cancer Cells | 1 |
| First line Treatments in Lung Cancer by University A | 2 |
| Lung Cancer Cases in Hospital of University B | 3 |
| First line Treatments in Breast Cancer (Institute C) | 4 |

**Table 2:**

| University Name | Keyword |
| --- | --- |
| University of ABC | University B |
| University of BCD | University A |
| University of CDE | Institute C |

I want to add a column of University Name to Table 1, based on the keywords search in the article title.  Given the keywords are highly similar, and can be found in different location in the article title, Vlookup cannot find the match successfully.

Vlookup (even with the option [true], i.e., not for exact match) cannot find the match correctly.

Are there any other formula or free tools can be used?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### INDEX/MATCH/SEARCH

Try this array formula (if you don't have Office 365 you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the formula):

```
=INDEX(Table2[University Name],MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table2[Keyword],[@[Article Title]])),0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### USING FILTER & FIND

Solution Credit to **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir -- Using `O365` & `Excel 2021` Function -- `FILTER()`

• Formula used in cell **C3**

```
=FILTER(E$3:E$5,ISNUMBER(FIND(F$3:F$5,A3)),"No Match")
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

### USING LOOKUP & SEARCH

You may try this formula as well, as shown in image below, works in all Excel Versions.

Formula used in cell **C3**

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH(Table2[Keyword],[@[Article Title]]),Table2[University Name])
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Comment: Beautiful. What does `9^9` mean?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir, If we are using the “Lookup column sorted in ascending order” form of LOOKUP, 9^9, 99^99, 1E+308 or other very large number will match the very last item in the list provided that the search keyword which returns a numeric data. The data in your lookup column don’t need to be sorted, because 9^9 will be larger than any possible value.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir, The LOOKUP function is it has the unique ability to ignore data that is a different type from the lookup value, and error values are definitely a different data type. So 9^9 will let you find the last matching value when you have one or more criteria that also must be satisfied. For example, suppose you want to find the value in column E when column B is “red” and column C is greater than 10. Then you need to use `=LOOKUP(99^99,1/((B2:B1000="red")*(C2:C1000>10)),E2:E1000) `

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir, The denominator in 1/((B2:B1000="red")*(C2:C1000>10)) will resolve into an array of 1 and 0. Since 1/0 is an error value, the array expression returns an array of 1 and DIV/0! error values. LOOKUP ignores those error values, and by looking for a very large number (which it won’t ever find), LOOKUP matches the last row where both criteria are satisfied and returns the corresponding value from column E.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir, Bonus feature: LOOKUP formulas like this don’t need to be array-entered. 9^9 or 99^99 may also be useful in INDEX & MATCH formulas where you seek a row number based index that could be quite large. Suppose you want to use an INDEX & MATCH formula for the previous problem. You might array-enter: `=INDEX(E2:E1000,MATCH(99^99,IF(((B2:B1000="red")*(C2:C1000>10))=1,ROW(B2:B1000)-ROW(B2)+1,""),1)) `

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir, you are much more experienced & knowledgeable than me, still don;t know why you asked, I learn from following your posts and other experts as well, but this one works, I have used lot of times & found success.!

Comment: I already told you that I'm weak in Excel formulas. In VBA I can do a lot. This was very educational for me since I often wondered about the 'tricks' with `LOOKUP`. You once more proved you're an Excel formula master. Keep up the good work.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sir, thank you very much for your kind words, however I dont think you are weak & Sir, you are very humble, I follow all your posts in VBA Solutions, the way you handle the arrays are just phenomenal, ! Thank you sir again for all the knowledge share!